# Typescript in keyword losing Intellisense when combined with Extract

Tags: typescript, types, intellisense

I am using react-query and would like to have my query strings be autogenerated but only ones that start with `get`. I would also like the query strings to have intellisense to the original function in VS Code when I hold down <kbd>CMD ⌘</kbd>. I have it working without the `get` filter. But for some reason, when I add filter it `Extract` it loses the intellisense.

Is there any way to keep Intellisense while filtering and using the `in` keyword?

```js
const API = {
  async getStuff() {
    return 1;
  },
  async putStuff() {
    return true;
  }
};

type QueriesTypeNoIntellisense = { [P in Extract<keyof typeof API, `get${string}`>]: P; };
type QueriesTypeIntellisense = { [P in keyof typeof API]: P; };
// swap out the type here to see the difference in intellisense.
export const QUERIES: QueriesTypeNoIntellisense = Object.keys(API).reduce((obj: any, k: any) => {
  if (k.startsWith('get')) {
    obj[k] = k;
  }
  return obj;
}, {});

QUERIES.getStuff;
QUERIES.putStuff;
```

With `QueriesTypeIntellisense`:
[image: With QueriesTypeIntellisense]

With `QueriesTypeNoIntellisense`: (Note: putStuff should be undefined because of the filter)

[image: With QueriesTypeNoIntellisense]

Comment: I don't see any "intellisense" difference between your two types. The only difference is that one of the has `putStuff` and the other one has not. What is the issue here? What are you expecting?

Comment: @TobiasS. `getStuff` is yellow in the first one and highlights the original function. The second one only shows the string value. When I CMD click on the second one nothing happens. When I CMD click the first one it sends me to the original function.